# Why is this.py encoded in Python?

Tags: python

Everybody knows that in python `import this` prints "The Zen of Python". Today I had a look at its source and found it is `rot13` encoded.

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

I know this is an Easter egg, but why is it encoded like this? Is it just for obfuscating the source? If so, I believe there should be much better ways of obfuscating Python source.

I'm just asking this out of curiosity. What can be a real, justifiable reason?

Comment: It's a handy way to violate both "Beautiful is better than ugly." and "Readability counts."

Comment: I think this is probably just out of fun - it would be boring to just have the whole poem in its original form, ready to be copy-pasted... or something like that.

Comment: So, the `zen` violates it in the definition itself. Is this entire thing a joke :)

Comment: @Anubis What, the Python zen? A code that doesn't respect it is a joke.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.python/0JORF8yc2P0/discussion

Comment: It keeps surprising me how SO is good at shutting really interesting questions like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's meant to be ironic, violating everything that could be considered, "The Zen of Python."